jsoup converting '&' to '&amp' when I set the Element
I am trying to parse an html input using jsoup (v1.18.1), extract elements, extract each attribute value and replace as follows:

> with &gt

< with &lt


The method I'm feeding this code into cannot have these symbols inside attribute values.
Below is the code I'm using
        Elements elements = htmlDocument.getAllElements();

        // Process each element's attributes
        for (Element element : elements) {
            // Iterate over all attributes of the element
            for (Attribute attribute : element.attributes()) {
                String originalValue = attribute.getValue();
                // Escape only '>' and '<' characters
                String escapedValue = escapeSpecificHtmlChars(originalValue);
                // Update the attribute with the escaped value
                element.attr(attribute.getKey(), escapedValue);
            }
        }

    private String escapeSpecificHtmlChars(final String input) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(input)) {
            return input;
        }
        // Replace only '>' with '&gt;' and '<' with '&lt;'
        return input.replace(">", "&gt;")
                .replace("<", "&lt;");
    }

Let's say the element is
<span role="text" aria-label=">test value>">Test value!</span>
Attribute aria-label has the value ">test value>"
escapedValue would be "&gt;test value&gt;"
But when I set the element using element.attr(attribute.getKey(), escapedValue);, the attribute value becomes "&amp;gt;test value&amp;gt;"
I want the escapedValue to stay as is when I set it as the attribute value.
Any help would be appreciated!

Are you sure your replacement is needed? Looks like it made automatically when you set attribute.

@talex Yes the replacement is needed. As mentioned, the resulting Document is being fed into another method which errors out if '<' or '>' symbols are present inside attributes.

Please show the document you are parsing with jsoup, then show what you get as parsed content. And/or show what you construct as document and what jsoup would send to the next parser. I second @latex and believe you are doing too much.

What format is the input of the next process expecting?

I think you misunderstood talex’s question.  We all agree the characters need to be escaped.  The question is:  do you need to escape them?  It is JSoup’s job, not yours, to make sure element content is escaped in the underlying HTML document.
